# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

Not sure what I am doing wrong exactly but keep getting this error while trying to save the bitmap into a png file:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
>   /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/HelloCamera/VID_20150806_124818.png:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
  private File getVideoThumb(String mediaPath, Uri videoUri) {
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaPath,   MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    File fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String[] tokens = mediaPath.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
    File f = null;
    f = new File(fPath, tokens[0] + ".png");
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmThumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "ERROR saving the compressed bitmap " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "ERROR closing out stream for file for bitmap");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     return f;
 }
```

The error seems to be pointed out being the repeat in directory `/storage/emulated/0/`

How do I take out the second one from this...  what regex I tried this:

```
int index = mediaPath.lastIndexOf("\\");
String fileName = mediaPath.substring(index + 1);
String[] tokens = fileName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
```

Comment: I guess "/storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/" should be "/storage/emulated/0/"? Your split operation does not seem to work as intended.

Comment: Maybe you can give us one example value of `mediapath`?

Comment: fhissen I see that is the error, how do I just grab out from media path being this /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/HelloCamera/VID_20150806_131011.mp4 then just this part VID_20150806_131011

Comment: If you know for sure mediaPath will be an absolute path:
 File f = new File(mediaPath);
 String name = f.getName();
 int i = name.lastIndexOf(".");
 if(i > 0) name = name.substring(0, i);

Comment: I want to save it as a different file name as a png since it is a thumbnail of the video

Comment: @Lion789 The String "name" contains VID_20150806_131011 only...

Comment: and I do not need it for saving new File with that name though?

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
File f = null;
f = new File(mediaPath);
System.out.println(f.getName().split("\\.")[0] + ".png");
```

you will get the last token you want.

```
Input: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/HelloCamera/VID_20150806_131011.mp4
Output: VID_20150806_131011.png
```

Comment: I want to save it as a different file name, as a png, since it is a thumbnail

Comment: MrT trying to add a png

Comment: i split it up and add the png.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing in the fileName to getVideoThumb thanks @fhissen for making me aware of the duplicate path... code looks like this now...

```
 private File getVideoThumb(String mediaPath, String mediaName, Uri videoUri) {
        Bitmap bmThumbnail;

//MINI 512x334
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

        File fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


        String[] tokens = mediaName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
        File f = null;

        f = new File(fPath, tokens[0] +".png");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {


            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bmThumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "ERROR saving the compressed bitmap " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "ERROR closing out stream for file for bitmap");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return f;
    }
```